# How to expand data before reshape in R

Tags: r, reshape, expand

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
as.is <- data.frame(Project = c('Proj A', 'Proj B', 'Proj C', 'Proj D'), 
               Start.Date = c('16.02.2015', '02.03.2015', '16.02.2015', '09.03.2015'), 
               Duration = c(3, 2, 2, 4),
               No.Of.Resources = c(3, 5, 2, 6))
```

I need to change the format so it looks like this:

```
to.be <- data.frame(Project = c('Proj A', 'Proj B', 'Proj C', 'Proj D'),
                '16.02.2015' = c(3, NA, 2, NA),
                '23.02.2015' = c(3, NA, 2, NA),
                '02.03.2015' = c(3, 5, NA, NA),
                '09.03.2015' = c(NA, 5, NA, 6),
                '16.03.2015' = c(NA, NA, NA, 6),
                '23.03.2015' = c(NA, NA, NA, 6),
                '30.03.2015' = c(NA, NA, NA, 6))
```

I can't work out how to expand out the dates so I get one per line so I can use reshape2 on the data. I can get as far as getting a list of lists of the dates that I want to be my titles, but can't see how to put the pieces together.

What's the right way to attack this problem?

edit: To clarify, Duration is the number of weeks, so I need to generate columns with titles of x, x+7, x+14...

Comment: How would you like to treat records with duplicate dates (e.g. rows 1,3 in `as.is`)?

Comment: @Marat Talipov Concatenated into a single column. I assumed that I'd be doing some kind of melt to get the data in long format and a cast to spread it which would bring multiple references together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach that seems to work. It uses `expandRows` and `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package, and then `dcast.data.table` from "data.table" to spread the values into a wide form:

```
as.is$Start.Date <- as.Date(as.character(as.is$Start.Date), "%d.%m.%Y")

library(splitstackshape)
dcast.data.table(
  getanID(
    expandRows(as.is, "Duration"), 
    c("Project", "Start.Date"))[
      , Start.Date := Start.Date + (.id-1) * 7], 
  Project ~ Start.Date, value.var = "No.Of.Resources")
#    Project 2015-02-16 2015-02-23 2015-03-02 2015-03-09 2015-03-16 2015-03-23 2015-03-30
# 1:  Proj A          3          3          3         NA         NA         NA         NA
# 2:  Proj B         NA         NA          5          5         NA         NA         NA
# 3:  Proj C          2          2         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
# 4:  Proj D         NA         NA         NA          6          6          6          6
```

---

This is a case where "dplyr" does make for nicer reading of the solution:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

as.is$Start.Date <- as.Date(as.character(as.is$Start.Date), "%d.%m.%Y")
expandRows(as.is, "Duration") %>%                   # expand the data
  getanID(c("Project", "Start.Date")) %>%           # add an "id" column
  mutate(Start.Date = Start.Date + (.id-1) * 7) %>% # recalculate start dates
  select(-.id) %>%                                  # drop the "id" column
  spread(Start.Date, No.Of.Resources)               # reshape long to wide
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd do this differently in `data.table`. Updated with a new solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(as.is)
dt[, Start.Date := as.Date(Start.Date, '%d.%m.%Y')]

# use dcast.data.table before version 1.9.5
dcast(dt[, list(seq(Start.Date, length.out = Duration, by = '1 week'), No.Of.Resources)
         , by = Project], Project ~ V1)
```

Old (and unnecessarily complex) solution:

```
# expand out Start.Date by Project
dates.all = dt[, seq(Start.Date, length.out = Duration, by = '1 week'), by = Project]

# set the key and do a rolling join, then dcast
# (can use just dcast in version 1.9.5+, have to use dcast.data.table before that)
setkey(dt, Project, Start.Date)
dcast(dt[dates.all, roll = TRUE], Project ~ Start.Date)
#   Project 2015-02-16 2015-02-23 2015-03-02 2015-03-09 2015-03-16 2015-03-23 2015-03-30
#1:  Proj A          3          3          3         NA         NA         NA         NA
#2:  Proj B         NA         NA          5          5         NA         NA         NA
#3:  Proj C          2          2         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#4:  Proj D         NA         NA         NA          6          6          6          6
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [`tidyr`](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) package instead of `reshape2`. Although `tidyr` imports `reshape2` for doing some operations, I believe it is to be consider its successor.

```
# Convert to Date class to sort the columns correctly
as.is$Start.Date <- as.Date(as.character(as.is$Start.Date), "%d.%m.%Y")

intermediate <- with(as.is, data.frame(
    Project = rep(Project, Duration),
    Date = rep(Start.Date, Duration) +
           7*(unlist(lapply(Duration, seq_len))-1),
    No.Of.Resources = rep(No.Of.Resources, Duration)
))

require(tidyr)
result <- spread(intermediate, Date, No.Of.Resources)
```

Looking at result you get

```
  Project 2015-02-16 2015-02-23 2015-03-02 2015-03-09 2015-03-16 2015-03-23
1  Proj A          3          3          3         NA         NA         NA
2  Proj B         NA         NA          5          5         NA         NA
3  Proj C          2          2         NA         NA         NA         NA
4  Proj D         NA         NA         NA          6          6          6
  2015-03-30
1         NA
2         NA
3         NA
4          6
```

Calling `dput(result)` on it produces what you ask for

```
structure(list(
    Project = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Proj A", "Proj B", "Proj C", "Proj D"), class = "factor"),
    `2015-02-16` = c(3, NA, 2, NA),
    `2015-02-23` = c(3, NA, 2, NA),
    `2015-03-02` = c(3, 5, NA, NA),
    `2015-03-09` = c(NA, 5, NA, 6),
    `2015-03-16` = c(NA, NA, NA, 6),
    `2015-03-23` = c(NA, NA, NA, 6),
    `2015-03-30` = c(NA, NA, NA, 6)),
    .Names = c("Project", "2015-02-16", "2015-02-23", "2015-03-02", "2015-03-09", "2015-03-16", "2015-03-23", "2015-03-30"),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L))
```

Comment: @Backlin Yes. My problem is that duration means the project is going to last x weeks from the start date. If it were a single date I'd be ok, but I don't see how I turn the dd.mm.yyyy with a duration of 4 weeks into 4 rows in long format that I can then rotate (or do it all at once with dcast)